# The best way to parse a JSON in Dart

Tags: html, dart

I'm trying to load a json file from a URL and parse it within Dart. So I had tried the following code as suggested from some links when I google for it:

```
   HttpRequest.getString("hellknight2.js").then((response)
   {
     var model = new JSON.parse(response);
   });
```

However, it seems to not work anymore on Dart SDK version 0.4.3.5_r20602. What is the current best way to get a Json file mapped to an object in Dart?

Comment: If you change your import to `import 'dart:json' as JSON` then it should work.

Answer (score 39):

Simply use [json](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-convert/json-constant.html) of the [`dart:convert` package](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html). Here is an example :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final myJsonAsString = '{"a": 1, "b": "c"}';
  final decoded = json.decode(myJsonAsString);
  ....
}
```

See [Parsing JSON](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/#parsing-json) for more details.

Comment: I like importing json in lower-case, it feels more consistent with Dart style. i.e  import 'dart:json' as json

Comment: Sure, `JSON.parse` was initialy a static function of a `JSON` object that has been removed. When migrating an old code, it's easier to use upper-case for prefix because you have only the import statement to change.

Comment: As of March 2014 - import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

Comment: how to access a nested json? like { "btcinr": { "last": "2614342.0" } } and i want to display the value of "last"?

Answer (score 9):

in my case

> JSON.decode

didn't work.

**Instead I had to use :**

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

final json=JSON.jsonDecode(myJsonAsString);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution :) At first, you need to import the `convert` package:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

var res = json.decode(response.body);
```

then you can get values by key, like below:

```dart
print(res["message"]);
```

Comment: how to access a nested json? like {
    "btcinr": {
        "last": "2614342.0"
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

It depends on a lot of things.

Is the json text you get is an array or a map?

You can try with:

```
Map model = new parse(response);
```

Or

```
List model = new parse(response);
```

but you need to import [JSONObject by Chris Buckett](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject) into your package

```
import "package:json_object/json_object.dart";
```

You can install it from pubspec adding this dependency

```
json_object
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a new pub package for this:

[Victor Savkin - Serializers](https://plus.google.com/117126476314628351830/posts/Gz9dPo8DiN6).

I didn't use it but seems to me that it will suite you. Try it out

Comment: Above Google+ link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this package. [pub: g_json](https://pub.dev/packages/g_json/install)

```
dynamic model = JSON.parse(JsonStringFromAnywhere);

final name = model['name'].stringValue;
// OR
final name = model.name;
```