# Parse JSON to Map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get response from backend:

```
   {"measurements": {
            "pm10": {
              "name": "pm10",
              "value": 20.8647,
              "unit": "µg/m³"
            },
             "pm25": {
              "name": "pm10",
              "value": 20.8647,
              "unit": "µg/m³"
            },
             "o2": {
              "name": "pm10",
              "value": 20.8647,
              "unit": "µg/m³"
            }

        },
   "station": {
        "city": "{cityName}",
        "name": "{locationName}",
        "latitude": "54.353336",
        "longitude": "18.635283"
    }
    }
```

This is what I got at this moment:

```
class Pollutions {

    Pollutions.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> map):
                measurements = Measurements.fromJsonMap(map["measurements"]),
                station = Station.fromJson(map["station"]);

  Map<String, Pollution> measurements;
  Station station;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final data = Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['measurements'] = measurements == null ? null : measurements.jsonDecode(measurements);
        data['station'] = station == null ? null : station.toJson();
        return data;
    }
}
```

and in measurements I can get other values and I don't know anything about they names, it could be o2, o3, not only pm10 etc. Can I parse this measurements to map key-value, where key will be pm10, something like that: Map?
How should looks `Pollutions.fromJsonMap` and `toJson` methods for map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to parse a JSON in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866290/the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-in-dart)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply do it by using the *out-of-the-box* decoder from `dart:convert`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final response = await http.get(someEndPoint);
final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
```

Answer (score 11):

Above answer may give the error internal linked hash map is not a subtype of Map.

try this instead:

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.castFrom(json.decode(jsonString))
```

Comment: This little tidbit was super helpful!

Answer (score 9):

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(yourVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonResponse =  convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35094782)