# Advanced json parse in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

I want to parse this Json. Now i am parsing `Load` as a class with 2 fields: `id`, and `value`. But what i want to is to parse it like `Map<int, String>`. When i am trying to cast the object, flutter gives me an error. for example:

```
Map<int, String> map = {
  38 : "#1038 Fort Dodge, IA - Algona, IA",
  39 : "#1039 Louisville, KY - Louisville, KY"
}
```

it is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770722/parse-json-to-map-in-flutter)

```
{
    "loads": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 38,
          "value": "#1038 Fort Dodge, IA - Algona, IA"
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "value": "#1039 Louisville, KY - Louisville, KY"
        }
      ]
    },
    "date_ranges": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "all_time",
          "value": "All"
        },
        {
          "id": "this_year",
          "value": "This year"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON to Map in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770722/parse-json-to-map-in-flutter)

Comment: No(( Actually that is a general question, not advanced((

Comment: @AkbarPulatov please have a look my answer, it will be helped you

Answer (score 0):

There was a issue you found because `loads` and `date_ranges` contain same child name `data` but there properties are different that's why your model class return error

Here I write a code for loads, please have a look

```
void main() {

 Map<int, String> map = {
};
  
  var mapdata = {
    "loads": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 50,
          "value": "#1038 Fort Dodge, IA - Algona, IA"
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "value": "#1039 Louisville, KY - Louisville, KY"
        }
      ]
    },
    "date_ranges": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "all_time",
          "value": "All"
        },
        {
          "id": "this_year",
          "value": "This year"
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  TestModel test = TestModel.fromJson(mapdata);
  test.loads.data.forEach((e)=>map[e.id]=e.value);
  
  print(map);
}

class TestModel {
  Loads loads;
  Loads dateRanges;

  TestModel({this.loads, this.dateRanges});

  TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    loads = json['loads'] != null ? new Loads.fromJson(json['loads']) : null;
    dateRanges = json['date_ranges'] != null
        ? new Loads.fromJson(json['date_ranges'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.loads != null) {
      data['loads'] = this.loads.toJson();
    }
    if (this.dateRanges != null) {
      data['date_ranges'] = this.dateRanges.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Loads {
  List<Data> data;

  Loads({this.data});

  Loads.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  var id; // here changes the type
  String value;

  Data({this.id, this.value});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

map result:

```
{50: #1038 Fort Dodge, IA - Algona, IA, 39: #1039 Louisville, KY - Louisville, KY}
```

N.B: Make your id dynamic with `var` type

Comment: You did not catch the question. Class with fields `id`, and `value` is method now i am using, but what was asked is not having a new class, but using `Map<int, String>` type. for example `Map<int, String> map = {38: "#1038 Fort Dodge, IA - Algona, IA"}`.

Comment: do you want to cast your data to map data with id and value properties?

Comment: casting is not working. it will probably look like `Map<int, String> map = {}; map[json["id"]] = json["value"];`

Comment: updated my answer please check

Comment: there should not be fields like `id` `value`. they are just key and values of Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pojo class to parse your JSON

```
TestModel testModel = TestModel.fromJson(yourResponse);


 class TestModel {
  Loads loads;
  Loads dateRanges;

  TestModel({this.loads, this.dateRanges});

  TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    loads = json['loads'] != null ? new Loads.fromJson(json['loads']) : null;
    dateRanges = json['date_ranges'] != null
        ? new Loads.fromJson(json['date_ranges'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.loads != null) {
      data['loads'] = this.loads.toJson();
    }
    if (this.dateRanges != null) {
      data['date_ranges'] = this.dateRanges.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Loads {
  List<Data> data;

  Loads({this.data});

  Loads.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int id;
  String value;

  Data({this.id, this.value});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String id;
  String value;

  Data({this.id, this.value});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: For your kind information, you will be got error because in your pojo class you defined two classes with same name