# How to parse json response in flutter?

Tags: json, parsing, flutter

I have a json response like this,

```
[{"name":"Bangladesh","info":"{\"summary\": [[\"DataSource\", \"Worldometers\"], [\"Country\", \"Bangladesh\"], [\"Total Cases\", 112306], [\"New Cases(24hrs)\", \"0\"], [\"Deaths\", 1464], [\"New Deaths(24hrs)\", \"0\"], [\"Recovered\", 45077], [\"Active\", 65765], [\"Total Tests\", 615164]], \"test\": [[\"Updated on 21-05-2020\", \"Total\"], [\"Test conducted (24hrs)\", \"10262\"], [\"Total test conducted\", \"214114\"], [\"Positive cases (24hrs)\", \"1773\"], [\"Confirmed\", \"28511\"]]}"}]
```

How can I parse this and save the data fields in such a manner so that I can use those as a variables like deaths, newCases etc in other widgets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The best way to parse a JSON in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866290/the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-in-dart)

Comment: I have went through a lot of articles about this, but my head cant make anythig out of that. I need the exact code of how can I do this in my scenario.

Comment: value of key "info" just a String or a object

Comment: Its just a json response that I got from an api. Its the output of response.body

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'dart:convert';

class Data {
  Data({
    this.name,
    this.info,
  });

  String name;
  Info info;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final _data = jsonDecode(json['info']);
    return Data(
      name: json['name'],
      info: Info.fromJson(_data),
    );
  }
}

class Info {
  Info({
    this.summary,
    this.test,
  });

  List<List<dynamic>> summary;
  List<List<String>> test;
  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Info(
      summary: List<List<dynamic>>.from(json['summary'].map(
          (element) => List<dynamic>.from(element.map((element) => element)))),
      test: List<List<String>>.from(json['test'].map(
          (element) => List<String>.from(element.map((element) => element)))),
    );
  }
}



 const data = {
  "name": "Bangladesh",
  "info":
      "{\"summary\": [[\"DataSource\", \"Worldometers\"], [\"Country\", \"Bangladesh\"], [\"Total Cases\", 112306], [\"New Cases(24hrs)\", \"0\"], [\"Deaths\", 1464], [\"New Deaths(24hrs)\", \"0\"], [\"Recovered\", 45077], [\"Active\", 65765], [\"Total Tests\", 615164]], \"test\": [[\"Updated on 21-05-2020\", \"Total\"], [\"Test conducted (24hrs)\", \"10262\"], [\"Total test conducted\", \"214114\"], [\"Positive cases (24hrs)\", \"1773\"], [\"Confirmed\", \"28511\"]]}"
};
```

Comment: How do I get the value of each elements like Deaths, or Recovered  and save them into variables? Besides, how do I connect this two model class with my code?

Comment: You can get the field value through index.  final data = Data.fromJson(data);   var deaths = data.info.summary[4][1].

Comment: For example, I have a api class for calling the response. Then after getting the response, how do I send it to your described class? And, then how do I get the value of each different keys so that I can use those values in some other classes?

Comment: You should be create a new class to contains all field. Example class Detail{

  String country;
  Detail({this.country});
  factory Detail.fromList(List<List<dynamic>> list){
    return Detail(
      country: list[0][1],
    );
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'convert' library of dart. Its pretty simple, you just need to encode your data in map format. for more details visit [dart:convert documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html)