# Flutter retrieve object info using json

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

They are not found in the same dart
JSON:

```
{
    "museum1" : {
        "info1" : "value1",
        "info2" : "value1"
    },
    "museum2" : {
        "info1" : "value2",
        "info2" : "value2"
    }
    ...
}
```

museum class:

```
class museo{
    String info1;       
    String info2
    
    museo({this.info1, this.info2});
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve **info1** and **info2** by knowing the id?
I would like to create **museum object** and just do **museum.info1**

Comment: Just decode the JSON and you can easily access its data. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867374/9455325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a simple entity you can define a factory constructor for create object from JSON data:

```dart
class museo{
  String info1;       
  String info2
    
  museo({this.info1, this.info2});

  factory museo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return museo(
      info1: data['info1'],
      info2: data['info2'],
    );
  }
}
```

And after JSON parsing extract objects:

```dart
final museos = parsedJson.map(museo.fromJson); // it should be List<museo>
```

But if your object large and complex in parsing, you can try to use plugins like [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable).

All JSON cast variants described in [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).