# api response body doesn't show up

Tags: flutter, api, dart

So I'm trying to get the access token from the Instagram API. it shows in Postman but it doesn't show up in the response body

```
    onPageStarted: (url) async {
      print("url is " + url);

      if (url
          .startsWith("https://aymen-ziouche.github.io/Gaming-website/")) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        var uri = Uri.parse(url);
        final String? code = uri.queryParameters["code"];
        print("this's the code: $code");
        final response = await dio
            .post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data: {
          'client_id': Constants.igClientId,
          'client_secret': Constants.igClientSecret,
          'grant_type': "authorization_code",
          'redirect_uri': Constants.igRedirectURL,
          'code': code
        });

        print("token is => ${response.data}");
        print("response => ${response.statusCode} ${response.data}");
      }
    },
```

---

here's the log:

```
I/flutter (21891): url is https://aymen-ziouche.github.io/Gaming-website/?code=AQDIXj5sEEPfgHv_U5dcw3A9zQbWjR9w37MTWg9f153UAJsyHcG34iNtSgxH9sswpBvHrB1CobZBgReCx4GhCIeq5HiLfIDRe8c_HNS_U_7CQ5fVdP6JdS1vLxQua4iA706q9lik08r_C9aAFLm6oT0hJeQVXcHiwTqJWLxxyXxWhtmeClBYwlIoSJKp8gcf-rft6QrVOolBcXg6LCB6Vj9W7Dr3k4QiqsDVN0vX2uvAsw#_
I/flutter (21891): this's the code: AQDIXj5sEEPfgHv_U5dcw3A9zQbWjR9w37MTWg9f153UAJsyHcG34iNtSgxH9sswpBvHrB1CobZBgReCx4GhCIeq5HiLfIDRe8c_HNS_U_7CQ5fVdP6JdS1vLxQua4iA706q9lik08r_C9aAFLm6oT0hJeQVXcHiwTqJWLxxyXxWhtmeClBYwlIoSJKp8gcf-rft6QrVOolBcXg6LCB6Vj9W7Dr3k4QiqsDVN0vX2uvAsw
I/flutter (21891): token is =>
I/flutter (21891): response => 200
```

I fixed it. the problem was in dio.options() I added this: `Options(responseType: ResponseType.json)`

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide your log's screenshot... like what API is replying exactly

Comment: yea sorry. here it is

Answer (score 1):

Add “Content-Type”: “application/json” and “Accept”: “application/json” to the headers parameters of your dio.post() method

Answer (score 0):

According to [the package example](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#examples), you should use `response.data.toString()` if you want to print it.

If you want to use it, properly [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866290/the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-in-dart) it first.

Comment: tried it. not working